# Modifying duplicate Key value on entry to Dictionary (C#)

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a requirement where I would like to use a dictionary to store "key=value" pairs, however now I need to store "duplicate" key values.

I have a line of delimited text (delimited with a pipe character ("|") which I split up into an array and then into a dictionary (see below)

```
string[] t = rawMessage.Split(new[] { '|', '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            message = t.ToDictionary(s => s.Split('=')[0], s => s.Split('=')[1]);
```

This works fine if no duplicates exist but I want to store duplicate keys in a way that adjusts the key value before insertion.

example

```
A=1|B=2|C=3|D=4|D=5|D=5
```

I want the key value to be adjusted to something like:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4
D[1]=5
D[2]=5
```

So then I can pull out the entry of the 2nd and 3rd "D" entries as they have a new key value.

Each duplicate is a unqiue record, as such I would like to be able to reference then in the order they were entered. the forth entry would be D[4] for example. A suggestion on using the same key value for all the values, may/will be confusing and I may end up pulling the wrong information (but will keep it in mind).

I would like to avoid having to loop through the array beforehand, and wondered if anyone knows a way I can perform this on the ToDictionary part of the code above.

Apologies for the fairly basic explaination.
Many of the threads deal with removing dupes in dictionaries and I understand that this is not the intended use of a dictionary.

Comment: You'll have to design your own data structure to keep track of the duplicates. Or do what @itsme86 said. But it depends on how you want to retrieve that information.

Comment: How are consumers of your dictionary to know if they want the first `D` key or the second one?

Comment: Quantic - The first entry would be D, the second D[1], the third D[2] and so on. The format of "[ ]" is just something to uniquely insert the key. They would then input the key they would like to see.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to associate multiple values with a key, you could just make the value part of the pair a list:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<char, List<int>>();

char key = 'D';
int value = 5;

if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict[key] = new List<int>();
dict[key].Add(value);
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. Done it before. Many of times.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is each duplicate key is a seperate record, so bunching them together means I would lose the ability to pull out the data based on the unqiue value. I will update the question with a bit more detail.

Comment: @Arclight I'm not sure I follow. You could just do `dict['D'][1]` to get the 2nd D entry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` to group the result set by the key, then flatten the groupings using `SelectMany,` projecting the desired key using the `Select` method overload with index parameter:

```
var message = t
    .Select(s => s.Split('='))
    .GroupBy(s => s[0], s => s[1])
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((v, i) => new
    {
        Key = i == 0 ? g.Key : g.Key + "[" + i + "]",
        Value = v
    }))
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a dictionary with a collection-based value:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>>
```

You can then use the best data structure for the job you need, but `List<>` is a good default.

Or you can use the `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` class, but this doesn't give array indexing on the value elements:

```
Lookup<string, int>
```

Which supports groupings under the key (so an enumerable of `TElement`). The docs for it are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Alternatively still, roll your own data structure, but it is very unlikely this would be required - a composite of existing things will likely work for you well enough.

Comment: @Fabio Fair enough. I'll leave it for your comment to add - the OP doesn't really state much about usage other than being able to index in the order they were inserted, which `Lookup` doesn't actually provide either way, but I sense that's an XY Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well..I'm going to a basic answer,without using LINQ. What i would do is make my own `ToDictionary` method, just checking if a key exists and if it does,create the new key and add it to the `Dictionary`, something like this:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> ToDictionary(string[] t)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string s in t)
    {
        string[] reg = s.Split('=');
        int i = 1;
        while (dict.ContainsKey(reg[0]))
        {
            if (!reg[0].Contains('['))
                reg[0] = reg[0] + "[" + i.ToString() + "]";
            else
                reg[0] = reg[0].Replace((i - 1).ToString(), i.ToString());
            i++;
        }

        dict.Add(reg[0], reg[1]);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

This can easily be converted in an extension Method.

Answer (score 0):

Like Adam Houldsworth said you can use `Lookup`.

Here is a snippet based on Adam Houldsworth's answer.

```
var str = @"A=1|B=2|C=3|D=4|D=5|D=5";
string[] t = str.Split(new[] { '|', '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var message = t.ToLookup(s => s.Split('=')[0], s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split('=')[1]));
var res = message.ToDictionary(i=>i.Key, x=>x.LastOrDefault());
```

Edit:

After reading your question again I understand you want the D=4 value also.

```
var res = message.SelectMany(i => i.Select((x, y) => new
{
    Key = i.Key,
    Value = x
})).GroupBy(q=>q.Value)
   .SelectMany(x=>x.ToLookup(xx=>xx.Key, xx=>xx.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way would be to use NameValueCollection in System.Collections.Specialized. The interesting thing with NameValueCollection is that if there are duplicate values for the same key, it will keep the values in the same key as comma separated value. The key will be the same this way, but the values you might have to separate it out.
A quick sample and output is given below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NameValueCollection col = new NameValueCollection();
        col.Add("A", "1");
        col.Add("A", "2");
        col.Add("B", "0");
        col.Add("B", "1");
        col.Add("B", "3");
        col.Add("D", "1");
        foreach (string key in col.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key + " " + col[key] + "\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output**
A 1,2
B 0,1,2
D 1
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3hWs.png)